# jQuery Post: Adding Form fields after a Post with Ajax call to an existing HTML FORM

Tags: html, forms, jquery, jquery-post

I have a web page using jQuery and ColdFusion that is divided into 4 sections. Each section is it's own logic, on the initial load of the page, all are loaded into the main page, and all the form sections fall under one main FORM ID, with on master Submit button to do the final processing.

3 out of the 4 sections are pretty much static, in that nothing gets reloaded into it.

The 4th section, when a change is made, does an AJAX Post, the information is processed in the results page, and the 4th section gets dynamically recreated to show the changes that were made and display new information.

However, when the page gets reloaded, any further attempts to pass those form variables in the 4th section fail. When the page gets reloaded, the 4th section reloads the fields and the associated code, but the fields are not connected with the existing FORM ID.

Here is the code I am using... The code works fine.  What I need help on is taking the fields that are sent back from the called page, and add those to the FORM.

```
function myclick1(){
    var uomid = $("#addUOMID").val();
    if (uomid > 0){
        $.ajax({            
            type: "Post",
            url: '_inc/dsp_v_UOM.cfm',
            data: $("#editPart").serialize(),
            success: function(html){
                $("#v_UOM").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Doug

Comment: i'm thinking you want to use the load() jquery function to bring in the html data from the other page.. but your question is not very clearly worded.